# Возможно ли сократить этот код?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, инспекция-кода

InlineKeyboardMarkup может иметь как параметр `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<>>` , но как я знаю это НЕ то же самое что и обычный двумерный массив `InlineKeyBoardButton[,]`. Попытка привести всё к одномерному массиву заканчивается печально : телеграмм из 30 кнопок выводит только 8 потому как только они помещаются в один ряд . То что я "захардкодил" работает, но выглядит очень криво и думаю это можно упростить , правда?

```
private static InlineKeyboardMarkup GetButtons(int count)
{
    InlineKeyboardMarkup markup;
    switch (count) 
    {
        case 28:
            markup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
            {
                new[]{InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("1","day_1"),InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("2","day_2"),InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("3","day_3"),InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("4","day_4"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("5","day_5")},
                new[]{InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("6","day_6"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("7", "day_7"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("8", "day_8"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("9", "day_9"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("10", "day_10")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("11", "day_11"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("12", "day_12"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("13", "day_13"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("14", "day_14"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("15", "day_15")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("16", "day_16"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("17", "day_17"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("18", "day_18"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("19", "day_19"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("20", "day_20")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("21", "day_21"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("22", "day_22"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("23", "day_23"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("24", "day_24"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("25", "day_25")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("26", "day_26"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("27", "day_27"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("28", "day_28") }
            });
            break;
        case 29:
            markup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
            {
                new[]{InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("1","day_1"),InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("2","day_2"),InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("3","day_3"),InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("4","day_4"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("5","day_5")},
                new[]{InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("6","day_6"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("7", "day_7"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("8", "day_8"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("9", "day_9"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("10", "day_10")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("11", "day_11"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("12", "day_12"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("13", "day_13"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("14", "day_14"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("15", "day_15")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("16", "day_16"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("17", "day_17"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("18", "day_18"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("19", "day_19"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("20", "day_20")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("21", "day_21"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("22", "day_22"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("23", "day_23"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("24", "day_24"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("25", "day_25")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("26", "day_26"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("27", "day_27"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("28", "day_28"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("29", "day_29") }
            });
            break;
        case 30:
            markup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
            {
                new[]{InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("1","day_1"),InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("2","day_2"),InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("3","day_3"),InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("4","day_4"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("5","day_5")},
                new[]{InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("6","day_6"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("7", "day_7"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("8", "day_8"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("9", "day_9"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("10", "day_10")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("11", "day_11"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("12", "day_12"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("13", "day_13"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("14", "day_14"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("15", "day_15")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("16", "day_16"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("17", "day_17"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("18", "day_18"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("19", "day_19"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("20", "day_20")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("21", "day_21"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("22", "day_22"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("23", "day_23"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("24", "day_24"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("25", "day_25")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("26", "day_26"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("27", "day_27"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("28", "day_28"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("29", "day_29"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("30", "day_30") }
            });
            break;
        case 31:
            markup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
            {
                new[]{InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("1","day_1"),InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("2","day_2"),InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("3","day_3"),InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("4","day_4"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("5","day_5")},
                new[]{InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("6","day_6"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("7", "day_7"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("8", "day_8"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("9", "day_9"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("10", "day_10")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("11", "day_11"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("12", "day_12"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("13", "day_13"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("14", "day_14"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("15", "day_15")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("16", "day_16"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("17", "day_17"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("18", "day_18"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("19", "day_19"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("20", "day_20")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("21", "day_21"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("22", "day_22"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("23", "day_23"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("24", "day_24"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("25", "day_25")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("26", "day_26"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("27", "day_27"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("28", "day_28"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("29", "day_29"), InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("30", "day_30")},
                new[]{ InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("31", "day_31") }
            });
            break;
        default:
            markup = null;
            break;
    }
    return markup;
}
```

Comment: Здесь задают вопросы на русском языке.

Comment: Вы можете перевести вопрос на русский язык или задать его на [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Почитайте описание метки "инспекция-кода", она поможет сделать вопрос лучше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var markup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(Enumerable.Range(1, count).Select(x => InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(x.ToString(), "day_" + x)).ToArray());
```

Вложенными массивами по 5 штук:

```
var markup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup
(
  Enumerable.Range(0, (count + 4) / 5)
  .Select(x => x * 5)
  .Select
  (
    x => Range(x + 1, Math.Min(5, count - x))
    .Select(x => InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(x.ToString(), "day_" + x))
    .ToArray()
  )
  .ToArray()
);
```

Comment: Я тоже так же само написал , но из 30 кнопок телеграмм может вывести максимум только 8 , если это одномерный массив как у вас. На stackoverflow на английском мне дали подсказку : использовать jagged массив или list<list<>>

Comment: @Artub34, не заметил. Вроде сделал группами по 5 шт.

Comment: Все работает , огромное спасибо

Comment: Меня удивило что вы смогли всё запихнуть в LINQ запрос и ничего лишнего , жесть

Comment: @Artub34, в linq можно всё запихать, [даже ёлки](//www.cyberforum.ru/vb-net/thread1014838.html#post5374782) :)